# Strapi, deep filtering with $not

Tags: filtering, strapi

Looks like strapi filtering doesn't work for nested arrays in cases with $not, for example I have a source array

```
[
  {
  id: 1,
  locale: 'en',
  localizations: [
    { id: 2, locale: 'de' },
    { id: 3, locale: 'sv'}
  },
  {
  id: 2,
  locale: 'de',
  localizations: [
    { id: 1, locale: 'en' },
    { id: 3, locale: 'sv'}
  },
  {
  id: 3,
  locale: 'sv',
  localizations: [
    { id: 1, locale: 'en' },
    { id: 2, locale: 'de'}
  }
]
```

if I try to get records without child 'en' like this

```
  filter: {
    localizations: {
      locale: { $ne: 'en' }
    }
  }
```

it still returns all 3 records, because there is a `localizations` object that is not equal to `en` for each of the main objects. I tried `$notContain` but it doesn't work as well, any ideas how it can be filtered?

Answer (score 0):

We spent a long time figuring out why filters are not applied to nested GraphQL types. Turns out you need to enable the `find` and `findOne` permissions on the `public` role for each API route.

Go to **Settings > Users & Permissions Plugin: Roles > Public** then expand the permissions for each route and ensure `find` and `findOne` is checked.

We enabled this functionality programmatically with the following script in index.ts:

```js
const boostrapPermissions = async (strapi: Strapi) => {
  const roles = await strapi.service('plugin::users-permissions.role').find();

  const _public = await strapi
    .service('plugin::users-permissions.role')
    .findOne(roles.filter((role) => role.type === 'public')[0].id);

  // Iterate over all api content-types
  Object.keys(_public.permissions)
    .filter((permission) => permission.startsWith('api'))
    .forEach((permission) => {
      const controller = Object.keys(_public.permissions[permission].controllers)[0];

      // Enable find
      _public.permissions[permission].controllers[controller].find.enabled = true;

      // Enable findOne if exists
      if (_public.permissions[permission].controllers[controller].findOne)
        _public.permissions[permission].controllers[controller].findOne.enabled = true;
    });

  await strapi.service('plugin::users-permissions.role').updateRole(_public.id, _public);
};
```

Invoke the above function in the `bootstrap` function:

```js
  /**
   * An asynchronous bootstrap function that runs before
   * your application gets started.
   *
   * This gives you an opportunity to set up your data model,
   * run jobs, or perform some special logic.
   */
  async bootstrap({ strapi }: { readonly strapi: Strapi }) {
    await boostrapPermissions(strapi);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter by locale, you can use `'locale'` as a parameter in the following format: `{ filters: {...}, populate: {...}, locale: 'en' }`. For other fields, using `$ne` has proven to work as expected. I hope this helps.